# Speed up Integrate around Max/Min or Piecewise

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

[`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) around a convex combination of two functions containing `Min` or `Max` or `Piecewise` does not finish in 5 min. By contrast, [`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) finishes in a second or two when the argument is one linear function, and similarly when the argument contains one function with [`Min`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Min.html) or [`Max`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Max.html) or [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html), and similarly when the argument contains a convex combination of linear functions. 
In the example below, the integrals of `d`, `da`, `d1`, `d2` take <2s and the integrals of `d1a`, `d2a` do not finish in 5 min.

Am I making some simple mistake or how to speed up similar integrals of convex combinations of `Piecewise` functions?

MWE:

```
Clear[d, d1, d2, da, d1a, d2a, cdf, pdf, cdf1, pdf1, cdf2, pdf2, s,
vi, vj, vlo, mui, muj, pi, pj, pis, pjs]
$Assumptions = 
  Flatten@{Thread[0 < {s, pi, pj, pis, pjs, vlo, vi, vj}], s < 1};
cdf[v_] = v - vlo; pdf[v_] = 1;
cdf1[v_] = Max[0, Min[1, v - vlo]]; pdf1[v_] = 1;
cdf2[v_] = 
 Piecewise[{{0, v < vlo}, {v - vlo, vlo <= v <= vlo + 1}, {1, 
    v > vlo + 1}}]; 
pdf2[v_] = 
 Piecewise[{{0, v < vlo || v > vlo + 1}, {1, vlo <= v <= vlo + 1}}];
d[pi_, pj_, s_, pis_] = 
  Integrate[(1 - cdf[Max[pi, vj - pj + pi - s]])*pdf[vj], {vj, vlo, 
    vlo + 1}];
d[0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.25] /. {vlo -> 0.1, mui -> 0.4}
da[pi_, pj_, s_, pis_] = 
  Integrate[(mui*(1 - cdf[Max[pi, vj - pj + pi - s]]) + (1 - mui)*(1 -
          cdf[Max[0, vj - pj] + Max[pi, pis + s]]))*pdf[vj], {vj, vlo,
     vlo + 1}];
da[0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.25] /. {vlo -> 0.1, mui -> 0.4}
d1[pi_, pj_, s_, pis_] = 
  Integrate[(1 - cdf1[Max[pi, vj - pj + pi - s]])*pdf1[vj], {vj, vlo, 
vlo + 1}];
d1[0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.25] /. {vlo -> 0.1, mui -> 0.4}
d1a[pi_, pj_, s_, pis_] = 
  Integrate[(mui*(1 - cdf1[Max[pi, vj - pj + pi - s]]) + (1 - 
         mui)*(1 - cdf1[Max[0, vj - pj] + Max[pi, pis + s]]))*
    pdf1[vj], {vj, vlo, vlo + 1}];
d1a[0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.25] /. {vlo -> 0.1, mui -> 0.4}
d2[pi_, pj_, s_, pis_] = 
  Integrate[(1 - cdf2[Max[pi, vj - pj + pi - s]])*pdf2[vj], {vj, vlo, 
    vlo + 1}];
d2[0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.25] /. {vlo -> 0.1, mui -> 0.4}
d2a[pi_, pj_, s_, pis_] = 
  Integrate[(mui*(1 - cdf2[Max[pi, vj - pj + pi - s]]) + (1 - 
         mui)*(1 - cdf2[Max[0, vj - pj] + Max[pi, pis + s]]))*
   pdf2[vj], {vj, vlo, vlo + 1}];
   d2a[0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.25] /. {vlo -> 0.1, mui -> 0.4}
```

Using Simplify`PWToUnitStep@ does not seem to speed up the integration.

Python's Sympy package in Jupyter Notebook does symbolically integrate the functions above quickly. The integrals are not hard.